# how to run xUnit integration tests written using Restharp and web application at a time in visual studio?

Tags: c#

I have written integration tests for API using Restsharp and xUnit and i added this test project into existing web API project.
I am not able to run those xUnit integration tests in localhost because it needs application is in run and how can i run both projects (integration tests project and web application project) at a time??

Comment: You could run the application in terminal and tests in IDE.

Comment: can i run both in IDE ??

Comment: Well you can two IDE in parallel

Comment: ok. can u just tell me how to run application in terminal??

Comment: Please, see the answer below

Answer (score 0):

To run API in terminal:

Open `cmd.exe`, navigate to you API project folder (where .csproj file is).

Run command `dotnet run`.

Comment: i have tried using "dotnet run" command in terminal but getting build errors and in visual studio build is success.Is there any another way to do build

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio you could run multiple instances inside one studio: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/460160/start-new-instance-without-debugging.html